# inverse form of integer part function

Tags: calculus, functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions, inverse-function

I have been challenged by my math teacher to solve this problem:

$f(x)=2x+[3x]$.

The inverse function is wanted.

I have tested several things, but no answer has also checked Geogebra.

Answer (score 0):

The function you consider is a piecewise linear function. You should probably study each piece separately.

For each integer $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, find the interval in which $\lfloor 3x \rfloor = k$, and the range of values of $f(x)$ for $x$ in that interval. On that range, $f(x) = 2x + k$, for which the inverse is straightforward to find.

Then if you want to have an explicit formula, find how to express $k$ using $f(x)$. Note that there might be several solutions!

Comment: thanks for your answer but I think  the main point on this problem is to some how connect "2x" and "[3x]" but anyway I gonna consider your point and try again